# unexpected result from javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made somesimple js code but result is unexpected.
how this is possible?

```
var n = $("#mGrid tbody tr[class*='success']");
console.log(n.length);

for (var i in n)
{
    console.log("x");
}
```

**console**

> 2
>
> 202 x

Comment: You can just use `.each()` to loop through all the DOM nodes selected by `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means `202` times `x` was printed in the *console*. When you are using a `for..in` loop over an *object*, the enumerable property of the particular object will be iterated until the end of prototype chain of it.

Your object has 202 numerable properties both own and prototype properties.

For iterating over the jquery object, you can use `.each` like below,

```
e.each(function(){
 //$(this) the current element on the iteration.
});
```

Still if you want to use a for loop, then you have to do like below,

```
for (var i=0,i< n.length;i++) {
    console.log("x");
}
```

Comment: how can I iterate tr classes?

Comment: @Mert You can use the `.each` approach that I given above.